# Not getting a json output form axios

Tags: json, api, axios, mediawiki

I am using axios to retrieve data from Wikipedia Api.  This is the code I have writtent.

```
let axiosData = function(){
let searchString = $('#searchString').val();
console.log(searchString);
let Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="+ searchString + 
"&origin=*&callback=";
axios.get(Url)
 .then(function(res){
     var linkLists = res.data;
     console.log(linkLists);
 })
 .catch(function(){
     console.log("Error")
 });
return false;
}

$('form').submit(axiosData);
```

I am able to get an output when I console log it.  Which is the following:  In this case I am searching for the name Jon Snow.  How am able to access the json?

```
/**/(["jon snow",["Jon Snow (character)","Jon Snow (journalist)","Jon Snow","John Snow (cricketer)","Jon Snoddy","John Snow","Jon Snodgrass (musician)","Jon Snodgrass","John Snow College, Durham","John Snow, Inc"],["Jon Snow is a fictional character in the A Song of Ice and Fire series of fantasy novels by American author George R. R.","Jonathan George Snow HonFRIBA (born 28 September 1947) is an English journalist and television presenter.","Jon Snow may refer to:","John Augustine Snow (born 13 October 1941) is a retired English cricketer. He played for Sussex and England in the 1960s and 1970s.","Jon Snoddy is an American technology expert who is currently the Advanced Development Studio Executive SVP at Walt Disney Imagineering.","John Snow (15 March 1813 \u2013 16 June 1858) was an English physician and a leader in the  development of  anaesthesia and medical hygiene.","Jon Snodgrass is \"the guy with the glasses from Drag the River\".","Jon Snodgrass is a Panamanian author, born on July 27, 1941 in Col\u00f3n, Panama to John Alphonso and Olivia Jane (Chestnut) Snodgrass.","John Snow College is one of 16 constituent colleges of the University of Durham in England. The College takes its name from the nineteenth-century Yorkshire physician Dr John Snow.","John Snow, Inc. (JSI) is a public health research and consulting firm in the United States and around the world."],["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snow_(character)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snow_(journalist)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snow","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Snow_(cricketer)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snoddy","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Snow","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snodgrass_(musician)","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Snodgrass","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Snow_College,_Durham","https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Snow,_Inc"]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At The beginning of the json has '/**/(' and at the end ')' characters which have cut by substring. After parsed it.

```
let Url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=jon%20snow&origin=*&callback=";
axios.get(Url)
.then(function(res){
 console.log(res);
 var linkLists = JSON.parse(res.data.substring(5, res.data.length-1));
 console.log(linkLists)
 })
 .catch(function(){
   console.log("Error...")
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If res.data is the JSON response for your http request you can parse that into JSON with the JSON.parse() function

```
var linkJSON = JSON.parse(res.data)
```

That will give you the json data in the linkJSON object.

Comment: Unfortunately I am getting an error.  I think axios is supposed to parse the JSON anyway.  I used the above URL to get around CORS.  Unfortunately, if I use the following ```"https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search="+ searchString ;```  I get CORS and I think axios does not handle JSONP.